# How to match the parent of parent value in pipeline of $lookup in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to filter the `rental_payments` that where `issue_from` is same as `rental_receipt.issue_from` (parent of parent), but not sure how to do that:

```
let rental_receipts = await this.req.db.collection('rental_receipt').aggregate([
  {
    '$lookup': {
      from: 'rental_contract',
      localField: 'rental_contract',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'rental_contract',
      let: {issue_from: '$issue_from'},
      pipeline: [
        {
          '$lookup': {
            from: 'rental_payment',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'rental_contract',
            as: 'rental_payments',
            let: {issue_from: '$issue_from'},
            pipeline: [
              {
                '$match': {
                  'issue_from': {'$eq': "$$issue_from"}, // not work
                }
              },
            ]
           
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  },
]).toArray();
```

Comment: I don't see you have declare any variable in pipeline but you use `$$issue_from` which is a variable. It's hard to help you as there is no sample input & output data. But what you need is declare a variable with [`let`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#std-label-lookup-join-let)

Comment: @YongShun I have tried and updated the question but still not working. I'm not sure how to use the `let` in nested `$lookup`.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. And also the `$match` stage should be as: `{ "$match": {  "$expr": {  "$eq": [ "$issue_from", "$$issue_from" ] } } }`. To use the variable, `$expr` is required.

Comment: @YongShun Thanks so much! Also find out that need to use `let: {issue_from: '$$issue_from'}` (double `$`)  in lookup of `rental_payments`.

Comment: No problem, good to see that you found the answer. Anyway, will recommend you to write it as answer post and accept the answer once it's available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @YongShun for the tips. Finally found the answer:

```
let rental_receipts = await this.req.db.collection('rental_receipt').aggregate([
  {
    '$lookup': {
      from: 'rental_contract',
      localField: 'rental_contract',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'rental_contract',
      let: {issue_from: '$issue_from'},
      pipeline: [
        {
          '$lookup': {
            from: 'rental_payment',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'rental_contract',
            as: 'rental_payments',
            let: {issue_from: '$$issue_from'},
            pipeline: [
              {
                '$match': {
                  '$expr': {'$eq': [ "$issue_from", "$$issue_from" ]},
                }
              },
            ]
           
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  },
]).toArray();
```